# MVC3 ASP.NET; How to add value in input[type="text"]?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, textinput

So currently, at my current employer we are using MVC3 ASP.NET with Razor. I think that is how you say it. Anyways, our input fields look something like this...

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress, new { @class = "text-box single-line" })
```

Now I understand what it is doing, don't need help on that. I need help on understanding how to place an value into that input field that it creates.

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 2):

You are already doing that with the `m => m.EmailAddress`.

You just need to populate your Model with that data:

In your controller:

```
return View(new MyModel
{
    EmailAddress = "foo@example.com",
});
```